# R - Assign ifelse output and data.table

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign a datatable to a new variable based on a condition (ifelse).

When I run the first line, the data table DT2 is returned as a list and only the values of the first column of DT1.
When I run the second line, the data table is correctly assigned to the variable as a data table with all columns and rows.

Why doesn't the first alternative work?

```
library(data.table)
DT1 = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3),y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
n <- 1

DT2 <- ifelse(n>0, DT1, NA) # line 1
ifelse(n>0, DT2 <- DT1, NA) # line 2
```

Comment: What is your desired output?  Neither of your two calls to `ifelse` make complete sense to me.

Comment: I need the datatable DT1 assigned to a new variable as a datatable, if a certain condition is met.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry, edited the first comment with a complete answer.

Comment: Please describe the condition you want to assign particular rows (or columns) to the new data frame. I suppose it has to do with some count, probably because you used `n` as condition. but currently n>0 is only a false value. You have to describe the condition.

Comment: There is no variable `DT` defined in your code, you probably intended to use `DT1` in those `ifelse` statements.  But in any case, as a workaround you may try just using a plain `if` statement.

Comment: You're right. It should be DT1 instead of DT on both lines. And thank you for your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `ifelse` is that it is vectorized, and you don't want this behavior for your logic.  You may try the following workaround:

```
n <- 1
DT2 <- NA
if (n > 0) DT2 <- DT1
```